I am trying to match section headers in PDF documents, few cases it's failing
This is the regular expression I have to match section headers in PDF document.
Regex = ^\s*(\d+\.?\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s{1,10}([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)
it's matching strings like 3.1 Introduction, 3 Battery etc., but it's not matching strings where 3.1\nIntroduction is present.
I also want to match cases like A1 Introduction, A1.1 String, B3 Battery Tests, I3.1 etc., Where A,B...Z is appended before numeric heading.
Can you share how to write two regex that works for these cases.
For detecting \n I tried few things like, ^\s*(\d+\.?\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\n?\s{1,10}([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*) - but this is not working.

Use a service like https://regex101.com/ to test your regex against test strings. Be sure to check the "Python" flavor on the right hand side pane.

I have modified your existing regex pattern to support strings similar to 3.1\nIntroduction.
Regex = ^\s*(\d+\.?\d*(?:\.\d+)*)(\s|\n){1,10}([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)
To support strings like A1 Introduction, A1.1 String, B3 Battery Tests, I3.1 etc., you can use the below regex
Regex = ^\s*([A-Z]{1}\d+\.?\d*(?:\.\d+)*)(\s|\n){1,10}([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)

If you want to support both the cases with a single regex pattern you can use the below pattern.
Regex = ^\s*([A-Z]?\d+\.?\d*(?:\.\d+)*)(\s|\n)+[\w\s]+
Here,

[A-Z]? - Checks for zero or one capital alphabet
(\s|\n)+ - Supports for one or more spaces or new line
[\w\s]+ - Matches with one or more the text or spaces

Verify the pattern whether it matches with all your use cases.

Try:
^[A-Z]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s{1,10}|\\n)(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ ?)+

See: regex101

Explanation

^: start of string
[A-Z]?: optional capital letter for appendix
\d+: followed by chapter number
(?:\.\d+)?: optionally follwoed by subchapter
(?:\s{1,10}|\\n): followed by either 1 to 10 whitespaces or literal \n
(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ ?)+: followed by capitalized word and possibly more space separated capitalized words (e.g. B3 Battery Tests)


\w?\d\.?\d?.*\n

\w?  This matches an optional character
\d   Followed by didget
\.?  optional point
\d?  optional didget after point
.*\n everything until linebreak
